# Select from list by index, but keep other associated items in list

Tags: python, list, indexing, enumerate

If I have a 2dlist of points like this...

```
myList=[['ab','0_3','-1','1'],['bm','2_1','-3','2'],['am','4_1','-1','3'],...]]
```

where `'-1','1'` for example are x, y coordinates (the last 2 columns) and I want display just part of the list with its index like this...

```
[0] ab    # I don't want to display the other list items, just the index and first col
[1] bm
[2] am
```

...so the user can select one of them by index number to make a point of origin. I figured I could enumerate as such...

```
for row in enumerate(myList):
     i, a= row
     col= (i, a[0])
     newList.append(col)
     print cols
```

But once I ask the user to select one ie. user selects '0' and that sets the variable `origin='ab'`, how can I get the x,y (or [2],[3]) columns associated with origin to use as the origin coordinates (I need to be able to compare to the rest of the list)?

Using this method, can I somehow use the variable assigned to the selected point ie. `origin = ab`, and then get it's x,y and assign them to x1, y1...
Because enumerate gives the 2 tuples (i, a) and appends them to `newList`, is that all I have in `newList`, or can I also append the other columns but not display them?
I hope my explanation is clear enough... I only have badly butchered code atm

---

So I finally got most of this working with...

```
import csv
myList=[]    
try:
    csvr = open('testfile.csv','r')
    next(csvr, None)
    theList = csv.reader(csvr)

    for row in theList:
        myList.append(row)

    for row in enumerate(myList):
        i, a = row
    print i, a[0]
except IOError:
    print 'Error!!!'


try:
   choice = raw_input("Select a set: ") # Can also enter 'e'
   if choice=='e'
      print 'exiting'
   else: 
        pass 
    user_choice = myList[int(choice)]   
    name, id, x, y= user_choice     
    print name, id, 
    return float(x), float(y)    
except:     
   print 'error'
```

It prints as expected and I can return x, y now which is great but it just keeps prompting me to enter a number. Any suggestions?

Comment: "Would the call simply be x1, y1=choiceFunction()? and adding return x, y to the above code" ... Perhaps. Certainly you *could* do it that way. To me, it seems that at the least, the csv file name should be a parameter that choiceFunction() accepts, rather than having no arguments. Having no arguments is better than having too many, but it's important to think about whether there are any things that you really __should__ be passing in as parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my post

Comment: Oh boy, that was stupid. I put it in a while loop and it seems ok now

Answer (score 0):

1) Keeping the list format, you can use the user's choice as a list index:

```
myList = [['ab','0_3','-1','1'],['bm','2_1','-3','2'],['am','4_1','-1','3']]

for row in enumerate(myList):
     i, a = row
     print i, a[0]


choice = int(raw_input("Select a set: "))
user_choice = myList[choice]

name, id, x, y = user_choice

print name, id, float(x) + float(y)  # use float() to convert strings to floats
```

Sample output:

```
~ $ python tester.py
0 ab
1 bm
2 am
Select a set: 1
bm 2_1 -1.0
```

Comment: I see what you mean. But if I ask for int input (index no), what if [2] and [3] are sometimes floats ie. -1.22, 3.10? Can I convert them when assigning to user_x, user_y?

Comment: If `user_x` is '-1.22' (a string), then you can use `float(user_x)` to get -1.22 (a float). Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: That is what I had in mind but would I put that line just below user_x=myList[choice][2]? Then I get "list indices must be integers, not str". I should also have mentioned 'myList' is a csv and read in using the csv module. It's not hardwired into the code

Comment: If you are using enumerate to number the choices for them, enumerate will always give an choice of integers. If you want them to select based on x or y values then that is different from what you originally described.

Comment: I expanded my answer a little bit, so you can see what I am getting at. I may not be understanding part of your question.

Comment: No sorry. I AM using enumerate to provide a number to choose (and I only want to display index and first item). But if I use enumerate to get these as tuples and append them to newList, I'm going to need to use the selected points x, y values in the list associated with the point selected, to perform later calculations

Comment: That's awesome and it works, but I'm also going to need to allow user to enter 'e' to exit as well as the choice of points in the list so int(raw_input...) wont work. I tried excluding int from the raw_input and converting to integer after a selection is made eg. user_choice=myList[int(choice)] but then I'm not sure how to deal with the floats. Sorry, I'm struggling a bit, but so close